# Conver pandas dataframe cell into list

Tags: pandas, dataframe, list

I have created the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 


ds = {'col1' : 
['1489900119222',
'1319900043111']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)

print(df)
```

Which looks like this:

```
            col1
0  1489900119222
1  1319900043111
```

I need to create a new column (called `col2`) which contains the values in `col1` arranged as a list. For example, the resulting dataframe would look like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If input are strings and ouput is list of strings use:

```
df['col2'] = df.col1.apply(list)
```

Or:

```
df['col2'] = [list(x) for x in df.col1]
```

---

```
print(df)
            col1                                     col2
0  1489900119222  [1, 4, 8, 9, 9, 0, 0, 1, 1, 9, 2, 2, 2]
1  1319900043111  [1, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1]
```

If input are integers and need list of integers:

```
ds = {'col1' : 
[1489900119222,
1319900043111]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)

print(df)
            col1
0  1489900119222
1  1319900043111

df['col2'] = [list(map(int, str(x))) for x in df.col1]
print(df)
            col1                                     col2
0  1489900119222  [1, 4, 8, 9, 9, 0, 0, 1, 1, 9, 2, 2, 2]
1  1319900043111  [1, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1]
```